# How do you sort columns left to right in MS Excel for mac?

Tags: ms-office

I have a table, and I'm trying to sort by the column headers, so that the alphabetically first column is to the left, etc. I've seen various instructions, and I've tried, but when I'm in the sort options, and select "left to right", and then "OK", it doesn't seem to change anything, and then I go back into options, it's back to up-down...

Is this a known bug? or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems like a bug. I'm not convinced that's what the 'left to right' option is for, but even attempting to use it for what it's for the option doesn't appear to 'stick'.

Comment: What exact version of Excel – 2016 or 2011?

Comment: I believe I'm using 2016 it looks like it's 2015, if that is actually a thing...

Comment: I was using 15.16. In 15.21.1 it appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rearrange columns alphanumerically by their names, assuming the column names are in row 1, do this:

1. Select all cells of the table. (Click and drag from top left cell to bottom right cell.)
2. Click the thin arrow button next to the 'Sort' button and choose `Custom sort…`.
3. In the Sort dialog box, click `Options…`, and in the pop-up, choose to `Sort Columns`.
4. Back in the main dialog box, un-check 'My list has headers'.
5. in **Row:** select `Row 1`; in **Sort On:** select `Values`; and in **Order:** select `A–Z`.
6. Click OK to execute.

(based on Excel 2011)

Comment: Right, I found those instructions, but as @grgarside mentioned, the "left to right" option doesn't actually stick.

Comment: Ok, it appears that this was fixed int some update that I hadn't installed yet.